# Jquery Autocomplete - Scrollbar not moving down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using Jquery Autocomplete widget to display tags to the user. As user types in results get displayed in a dropdown below.

**Issue:**
The records displayed are more than 10 thus applied scrollbar to ui-autocomplete class.
However when i reach the end of the visible record and i press the down arrow key then i see a flicker in the scrollbar and the mouse doesn't move accordingly.

Have referred the autocomplete API documentation and didn't find relevant information in bugs list.

Thus need your help Stackoverflow members. Kindly help me fix this issue.

**Code:**

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;   /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    z-index:1000 !important;
}
```

**Screencast uploaded here:**  http://www.screencast.com/t/r9Mp1uxD80o

Kindly let me know what will fix the issue and help scroll the results smoothly.

Thanks,
Ved

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code so that we can find the actual problem

Comment: With what code you have given, there seems no problem because the documentation itself suggests this method to be used. Add more code or create a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net